# Error when adding tags to a tag collection using AppSDK 2.0rc1

Tags: tags, rally

I keep getting the following error when attempting to add a tag:
*TypeError: Object has no method 'getModel'*

This is my code snipit:

```
_onRecordRead: function(record, operation) {
        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
            var tagStore = record.getCollection('Tags');
            defectStore.add({'_ref':'/tag/1234'});
            defectStore.sync({
                    callback: function() {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
            });
        }
    },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may load the store first by passing additional config to the getCollection method, and once it loaded you may the add and sync:

Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

```
launch: function() {
    console.log("launch");
   Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
        type: 'User Story',
        success: this._onModelRetrieved,
        scope: this
    });
},
_onModelRetrieved: function(model) {
    console.log("_onModelRetrieved");
    this.model = model;
    this._readRecord(model);
},

 _readRecord: function(model) {
    var id = 13888228557;
    console.log("_readRecord");
    this.model.load(id, {
        fetch: ['Name', 'Tags'],
        callback: this._onRecordRead,
        scope: this
    });
},

_onRecordRead: function(record, operation) {
    if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
         var tagStore = record.getCollection('Tags', {
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: { load: function() {
                tagStore.add({'_ref':'/tag/14749564725'}, {'_ref':'/tag/14749393316'});
                tagStore.sync({
                    callback: function() {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                });
            }}
        });
    }

},
```

});